# Stored procedure questiom

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create this stored procedure that lets you input the customer ID number and it will output the highest order total and the customer firsts and last name. This is what I got so far - can't seem to get what the error is

> Error Code: 1064.
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(o.TotalPrice) INTO HighestOrder FROM orders AS o JOIN cu' at line 6

Code:

```
 DELIMITER //   
CREATE PROCEDURE CustomerHighestOrders(IN CustomerID VARCHAR(3), OUT HighestOrder DECIMAL)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 
                c.FirstName,
                c.LastName
                MAX(o.TotalPrice)
            INTO 
                HighestOrder
        FROM 
            orders AS o
        JOIN 
            customer AS c USING(CID)
        WHERE CustomerIDNumber = o.CID;
    END //
```

Comment: *What* error? Can you please include the full error text?

Comment: Parameter is `CustomerID` but in WHERE you use `CustomerIDNumber`. Typo? And no comma after `c.LastName`. PS. BEGIN-END is excess in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a comma after c.LastName.
Also, I don't see you using CustomerID parameter anywhere. It should probably go in your WHERE clause. I.E: WHERE CustomerIDNumber = CustomerID;
If I understand it correctly based on what you're trying to do.

Comment: i want to be able to input a customer id and have the procedure output the customers name and highest order total

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need in

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE CustomerHighestOrders( IN CustomerID VARCHAR(3), 
                                        OUT HighestOrder DECIMAL )
SELECT MAX(o.TotalPrice)
INTO HighestOrder
FROM orders AS o
JOIN customer AS c USING(CID)
WHERE CustomerID = o.CID;
```

From the other side JOIN and WHERE by the same column `CID` looks strange...